# How to add Ultrasonic Sensor to the board?

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, sensors, pins, arduino-ide

I am making an RC car , have combined the **Arduino UNO R3** with the **AR 293d**, and pluged in the HC-SR04 sensor to the SRO4 hole at the left top corner in the below graph. However, besides one sensor  I **would like to add three more HC-SR04 sensor**.

Reference:
http://www.instructables.com/id/Simple-Arduino-and-HC-SR04-Example/

[image]

The problems are

1) is the board sufficient to plug three more sensor ?

2) or what extra board I need if not sufficient and how to combine those board

2) also, can I plug in other hole?

Thanks for helping

**Update: breadboard connection**

So I have to get a stuff like this?

http://www.tandyonline.co.uk/small-solderless-breadboard.html

and one more question, sorry for begin newbie, there are many holes on breadboard, which hole I should connect those three sensor on it, and the hold I should connect the breadboard with the AR-293D board?

And for programming, is there any way to get the pin at the breadboard as I have read some program before, the pin is assign with a number?

Thanks again for helping.

[image]

Comment: If you are in doubt on how to use breadboards and perfboards check out this video with collin: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w0c3t0fJhXU I would recomend watching everything he made - he is fairly entertaining and going in a steady pace where everyone can follow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Not really. You have so little space and you have to selder them. Try using wires

2) If you want it to be flexible use a sandard solderless breadoard on the center of the car and then with male-female jumperwires try connecting them.

3) The board has traces. That means some holes have a very specific purpose.

### Updated:

On every breadboard the holes are connected verticaly. For example, in the image from your breadboard you posted 1A, 1B, 1C, 1D and 1E are connected together.
If you would like to have all of the 3 sensors better use wires and then atach them on to your breadboard.

Here is a picture: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/3ij4w6eytio8p08/Screen%2016-25-31.png?dl=0

Comment: Thanks a lot, then I go for a breadboard, please have a look at update question.